# Is my algorithm wrong or it's right and just needs tweaks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math

```html
<html><head></head>
<body><script>
  function GCD(a, b) {
    if (a == 0) {
      return b;
    }
    return GCD(b % a, a);
  }

  function difference(array) {
    for (var i = Math.min(...array) + 1; i < Math.max(...array); i++) {
      array.push(i);
    }
    array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  }

  function smallestCommons(arr) {
    difference(arr);
    console.log(arr);
    a = arr[arr.length - 1];
    b = arr[arr.length - 2];
    var LCM = a * b / GCD(a, b);
    while (true) {
      var index = arr.findIndex(element => LCM % element !== 0);
      if (index === -1) {
        return LCM;
      }
      LCM *= arr[index];
      console.log(LCM);
    }
  }
  smallestCommons([1, 5]) // right 
  smallestCommons([2, 10]) // right
  smallestCommons([1, 13]) // wrong
  smallestCommons([23, 18]) // wrong
</script></body>
</html>
```

This is a code for this challlenge:
https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple/

The algorithm I use:

1-Calculate LCM of the two greatest numbers.

2- Try LCM % number on all the array and if you find a number that doesn’t return 0, assign it to the var index and multiply it * LCM then keep doing like that until it doesn’t find anything and returns -1 instead, when that happens, return LCM finally.

The code works at the first two arrays but it doesn’t work at last two which caused me to think, is my algorithm wrong and I’m just wasting my time trying to tweak it or it’s right and it just needs some tweaks?

Notice that there are 3 different functions, the first function calculates GCD to calculate LCM later, then the second function pushes the values between the two values in the array and then sorts it, and the third function calculates LCM(Lowest Common Multiple)

The problem is that the last second arrays:

smallestCommons([1, 13]) returns 4324320 instead of 360360

smallestCommons([23, 18]) returns 72681840 instead of 6056820

So what I want to know, please focus on this:

Is my whole way(algorithm) wrong and I need to rewrite a whole one or it needs some tweaks to work?

Please, don't give me ready codes. Just tell me what I want to know and thank you (:

Comment: I converted your code into a snippet. If you run the snippet you'll get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: BCD is not defined" - please fix that and then we'll see what else might come up... **N.B.** you can find that issue here: `if (index === -1) {
        return BCD;
      }`

Comment: @Matt Sorry for that! I changed the variable name later and I forgot to change all of them. I edited it now.

Comment: `LCM *= arr[index];` is the problem. For example, suppose the input was `[4, 7]`. Then you calculate `LCM = lcm(6,7) = 42`. Then you see that 4 doesn't divide 42. Doing `LCM *= 4` just so that `LCM % 4 == 0` is unnecessary: you could've just multiplied by 2. Instead of multiplying at the line mentioned, take the LCM.

Comment: Nevermind. The solution was to divide the number by its greatest common divisor so that it would be the recommanded/undivisible (prime) number, I guess. Thank you all for help! It solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong multiplying by `arr[index]`.

Let relabel our variables for clarity:

*N = array[index]

    p = GCD(LCM, N)*

now we can rewrite *N* and *LCD* as:

*N = p × q

    LCM = p × r*

to have the smallest number being lowest common multiple of current LCM and N you need to calculate it as:

*LCM := p × q × r*

But if you calculate it with code

```
LCM *= arr[index];
```

you in fact calculate

*LCM := (p × r) × (p × q) = p × p × q × r*

i.e. one *p* factor too much. To calculate it as needed you should use following code instead:

```
LCM *= arr[index] / GCD(LCM, arr[index]);
```

Comment: I didn't understand it well. Can you please repeat explaining it? Of course if it's fine to you.

Comment: Oooh! I understood it now. lol it took me whole 5 minutes to get it. I think what you're trying to say is that multiplying by arr[index] could be too much than the lowest so it will result falsely, instead, it's better to divide it by GCD to give us the result as a prime number that is the right answer since it's not divisible number by any other number so the result would be the Lowest Common Multiple. Wow, I'm trying in this 4 hours ago and never thought of doing that, thank you a lot for the explaination + solution!